# Spring Security logout GET vs POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security. I have 2 apps. They works in couple. And when I want to logout from one, it should also logout from another. I use default logout flow. On application A I click logout link:

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/app-b-logout" />

@RequestMapping("/app-b-logout")
public RedirectView appB_Logout() {
    return new RedirectView("http://appB/logout");
}
```

On application B I have following settings:

```
.logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout")
```

And logout success handler:

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
    implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
   System.out.println(authentication == null); // MAGIC HERE
}

}
```

And in line `System.out.println(authentication == null);` I have different results. If I redirect from application A, authentication is null, when I click LOGOUT button on app B (using post form), I have authentication object.
But in both cases user is logged out in result. But I need to do some stuff with authentication object. How to make redirect on app A to make a POST request or just how to get this authentication when I redirect from app A?

Comment: That's not an answer to your question, but probably you may want to think about implementing Single-Sign-On

Comment: @lenach87 do you mean CAS?

Comment: I was thinking of this http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-sso.html